# How to set and get request format in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I wonder if there's a way to get the "json" part from this url: "*/post/index.**json***", or, if not present, "html" by default, just like doing "request.format" in Rails.

I also wonder if this can be set on the routes as a param. Doing:

```
resources.router.routes.default.route = /:controller/:action.:format
```

on the ini file won't work, it seems like the only way to separate params is by adding /.

Is this possible with Zend or do I have to code it myself?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Rails or Ruby, but I think you'll have to code it yourself in ZF.  You can do this inside a controller:

```
$format = substr($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), -4);
if ($format === 'json') {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

But this depends on the format of the request being included in the URI of course.

Are you putting the format into the URI so you can respond to an AJAX request?  I think the way intended by those who wrote the HTTP spec would be to read the request headers given by the client, namely the [Accept](http://shiflett.org/blog/2011/may/the-accept-header) header.  I also use ZF's `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` to detect AJAX requests.

Comment: Well, I'm used to Rails where you can respond according to the format: index.xml would respond xml, index.json would respond with a json string (you do this by basically switching the format). By default the format is html so you respond with html. I guess I'll have to add some code to check the format automatically and add it to the Request object.